# $\lvert\operatorname{Aut}(F/K)\rvert$ divides $[F:K]$

Tags: field-theory

Let $F/K$ be a finite extension.
I want to prove $\lvert\operatorname{Aut}(F/K)\rvert$ divides  $[F:K]$.
I know  $\lvert\operatorname{Aut}(F/K)\rvert\leq [F:K]$ but I cannot show the former.

Take $\alpha$ from $K$, then $\lvert\operatorname{Aut}(F/K)\rvert＝\lvert\operatorname{Root}P_{\alpha}(K)$.
$[L:K]＝\deg P_{\alpha}$.
But I cannot go further. Thank you in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $G=\mathrm{Aut}_K(F)$. Then $F/F^G$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $G$. Thus, we have
$$|G|=[F\colon F^G]=\frac{[F\colon K]}{[F^G\colon K]}\Big\vert[F\colon K].$$

Comment: I endorse this answer over my own... hopefully OP sees this and changes the acceptance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very concise  answer. Could you explain more why F/F^G is  Galois ?

Comment: That's an important theorem in Galois theory. For $\alpha\in F$, you can look at the polynomial $f(X)=\prod (T-\beta)$, where the product runs over all conjugates of $\alpha$. The automorphisms permute these, so $f$ is a polynomial over $F^G$. Now, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is separable and splits. It follows that $F/F^G$ is separable. By the Primtiive Element Theorem, it is simple and it is then the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of a primitive element, hence normal and ultimately Galois.

Comment: Thank you, I found the lemma on my textbook. The lemma is used to prove fundamental theorem of Galois of finite version, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Every automorphism of $F$ over $K$ is determined by its action on a basis, which has $[F\colon K]$ elements. Thus, if the basis is mapped into itself by the automorphism group, then Aut$(F/K)$ can be represented as a subgroup of the permutation group on $[F\colon K]$ elements. Thus, the number of elements of Aut$(F/K)$ divides the size of the permutation group, which is $[F\colon K]$ factorial.

Your question asks about a much smaller bound, without the factorials. And for this we need a more refined approach. The way that the inequality $|\textrm{Aut}(F/K)|\leq [F\colon K]$ is proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141709/if-fe-infty-is-it-always-true-that-operatornameautf-e-leqfe?rq=1) is to decompose the finite extension into a tower of simple extensions. Both sides of the inequality are multiplicative, and for simple extensions it is straightforward to get the bound.

Now if you follow along in this proof, each time you obtain an inequality between two integers, it is actually showing that one divides the other. Hence your result follows.

An earlier version of this answer was incorrect. The example I was considering was the following: a cubic extension with automorphism group $S_3$, which I believed could be obtained from an explicit construction in the comments below. That construction is incorrect, and no such extension exists.

Comment: If the Galois group of the extension is $S_3$, it has degree $6$. Galois extensions are precisely the extensions for which $|\mathrm{Aut}(F/K)|=[F\colon K]$.

Comment: True, it was incorrect of me to refer to that as a Galois group. I meant to say automorphism group of an extension (the extension not necessarily being Galois). I have updated the wording in my answer.

Comment: This is a question from final exam in my university and the statement should be true...

Comment: @buoyant if you want to see it more concretely: take $K=\mathbb Q$. Let $p(x)=x^3+x+1$ and let $F=K[x]/(p(x))$. Discrimant of $p(x)$ is not a perfect square in $\mathbb Q$, thus the automorphism group is $S_3$. And $[F:K]=3$ since there is a basis given by $(p(x)),x+(p(x)),x^2+(p(x))$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3135410/automorphism-group-of-splitting-field-of-cubic-polynomial-over-mathbbq

Comment: Was my professor wrong?

Comment: All I can say is that if you are using the same definitions as me, your question is stated incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you very much for kind help!

Comment: This seems wrong to me. A degree $3$ extension can't have order $6$ automorphism group. As OP noted, we always have $|\mathrm{Aut}(F/K)|\le[F\colon K]$. The discriminant argument shows that the Galois group of the splitting field of $p$ is $S_3$, but the $F$ is obtained after just adjoining one root and in this case, that does not yield the entire splitting field.

Comment: @Thorgott you are right, I have made a serious mistake. And my example is not a counterexample, since not all permutations of the basis give rise to automorphisms. In particular the permutations must send fix the ideal $((p(x))$ and can only permute the remaining two basis elements. I will correct my answer.

Comment: The first two sentences of the answer don't make sense: the behaviour of an automorphism of a vector space is determined by its action on a basis, but, in general, it won't permute the basis. You ned to exhibit a basis that has to be permuted by the field automorphism.

Comment: (Some authors refer to $\mathrm{Aut}(F/K)$ as “the Galois group of the extension”, even when the extension is not Galois; so it’s not absolutely wrong to use that name, but usually a good idea to note that this is what you mean)

Comment: @buoyant my answer was wrong. I made some heavy edits to it and I believe it is now correct. But in the meantime a much better answer was posted. I apologize for confusing you.